# @Autowired field is null when used in new abstract class

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I have a bit of code that is working :

```
@Component
public class MessageUtil {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("processMessages")
    private ReloadableConfig config;
    
    public String createMessage() {
        return config.getPropertyStr("message.simple.signature");
    }
}
```

The bean `processMessages` is defined here :

```
<bean id="processMessages" class="com.company.framework.resources.ReloadableConfig">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:com/company/aaa/bbb/domain/service/processMessages"/>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="cacheSeconds" value="60"/>
</bean>
```

Then I created some new classes :

```
public abstract class MessageBuilder {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("processMessages")
    protected ReloadableConfig config;
    
    public abstract String createMessage();
}

@Component
public class SimpleMessageBuilder extends MessageBuilder {
    private String template;

    private void setTemplate() {
        template = config.getPropertyStr("message.simple.signature");
    }

    @Override
    public String createMessage() {
        setTemplate();
        return template;
    }
}
```

I now have a NullPointerException because in `setTemplate()`, `config` is null.
What's the problem in the second code ?

Comment: Where are you using the class `SimpleMessageBuilder`? Can you show that code?

Comment: Did you tried Setter based dependency injection? Field based injection is mostly a bad idea...

Answer (score 0):

@Autowired doesn't work neither on field neither on constructors of abstract classes. It works on setter of abstract class but be sure to make it final because if overwritten by concrete class behavior is unstable. An abstract class isn't component-scanned since it can't be instantiated without a concrete subclass.